# Как переместить браузерный alert?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, браузер, интерфейс

Защита лабы. Препод просит показать, как переместить браузерный `alert('sometext');`
Можно ли с ним взаимодействовать и как? Либ нет. Нативный js.

Comment: что значит переместить? Можно мышкой передвинуть :)

Comment: переместить куда?

Comment: ну, вот препод говорит переместить в левый верхний угол и задать ему красный цвет)00)

Comment: мышкой нельзя, думаю

Comment: @Anhk, поздравляют, преподаватель задал невозможную задачу :)

Comment: @Grundy а что, если переписать  `window.alert` со своим блэкджеком и .... ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, пока это вариант :) но не уверен, что задача была в подмене системного окна, на просто показ обычного элемента :)

Comment: @Grundy а как мне кажется, именно это и хотелось преподу. Во всяком случае нарисовать это, как вариант решения можно и ткнуть препода носом, если тот не ожидал))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это да :-) было бы забавно на это глянуть:)

Answer (score 3):

[alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) показывает блокирующее окно, к его настройкам нет доступа. Более того, на время его показа блокируется выполнение остальных скриптов. Таким образом пока оно открыто - ничего сделать нельзя.

---

Как подсказывает [@Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589755/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-alert/589757#comment790785_589755):

Можно переопределить функцию `alert`, например так:

```
window.alert = function(){
    ...
}
```

И внутри функции просто показывать абсолютно позиционированный элемент.

Comment: спасибо, так и передам ему :D

Comment: @Anhk, немного дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Мышкой. Навести на заголовок, нажать ЛКМ и передвинуть.